# TestComplete Menu Item

Tags: menu, toolbar, testcomplete

I am new to TestComplete. I have a question and it may be something impossible or too simple. I have a toolbar containg File, Edit, View, etc. I want to get one item (eg. Edit) to mapped objects. I can get the whole toolbar only. I want to simulate a click event on Edit. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, TestComplete does not work with menu items as with separate objects. It works with a menu object or even only with a menu's parent object and you can specify which item to select by passing the caption of this item to the corresponding method of a menu object. For example:

```
objMenu.Click("Edit|Paste");
// or
parent.MainMenu("Edit|Paste");
```

Please find more details on how TestComplete interacts with menus in the [Working With Menus](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/60550/) help topic.